# Error when Loading Native Ad Android in Custom Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to Load Native Ad in Custom Dialog. But When I am trying to do it, It Gives me the Following error.

```
Error :- java.lang.IllegalStateException: setAdListener must be called on the main UI thread.
```

The Method From which i am Calling Custom Dialog is

```
private void createPopupDialog() {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_download, null);
    streamButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.streamButton);
    downloadButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
    cancelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    adNativeView = (NativeExpressAdView)view.findViewById(R.id.nativeAD);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID)
            .build();
    adNativeView.loadAd(request);
    dialog.show();

}
```

How can I work around so that i can solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUiThread method from Android

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               // put your code to show dialog here.
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried it. But it gives me error:- android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Try executing this on a separate thread or remove this line and just show a dialog -> AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID) 
            .build();